# how to do URL abstraction in PHP

Tags: php

When i try to pass values in href

```
$query_string = 
    'id=' . urlencode($id) . 
    '&name=' . rawurlencode($name) .
    '&dob='. $dob .
    '&email='. rawurlencode($email);

print "<a href='update.php?$query_string'>Update Details</a>
       <br>Student ID: $id
       <br> Student Name: $name
       <br> Date Of Birth: $dob
       <br> Email ID: $email
       <br>";
```

I can see the url as this in the address bar:

```
localhost/student_portal/update.php?id=abc&name=Giridharan%20Rengarajan&dob=1993-07-22&email=rgiridharan.93%40gmail.com
```

in the update.php i am updating the values in the database with respect to the id mentioning in the link

```
$sql="UPDATE student_details SET student_name='$name',student_dob='$dob',student_emailid='$email' WHERE student_id='$id'";
    echo $sql;
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)==TRUE){
        $_SESSION['updateflag'] = 1;
        header("location:index.php");
    }
```

So if i change the id in the link the details of the another user is updated. I want to avoid this.

Comment: please familiarize yourself with our [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Apart from that, it's pretty hard to tell what you are asking. [Edit your question please.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17772432/edit) Why does it matter whether you edit the value in the address bar? What does that have to do with programming?

Comment: (1) Updates(anything that mutates data should be POSTs (2) An update is an update, if access is allowed, and people want to change something they should be able to (3) if there are limits on what are valid updates _validate them_.

Comment: Even POST can be tampered with, make sure you do post-validation

Comment: @Gordon now am i clear???

Comment: I am reopening it although the obvious answer is not to put the ID in the URL or to server side check whether the current user is allowed to change that ID. Apart from that, your code is wide open to SQL injection. Right now anyone can edit anything in your database. Bind your params.

Comment: I am sorry @Gordon since i am new to this topic i don't know SQL Injection earlier. Just now i did google about that. Yes this is what i am asking about...

Comment: if you absolutely *have to* pass sensitive data in the URL it would be a good idea to encrypt/hash it client-side and decode it server-side, but if not use `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the user ID is associated with that email first.

```
$db->query("SELECT id FROM student_details WHERE student_id='$id' AND student_emailid='$email'");
if ($db->numRows()) {
    // do update here
}
```

Alternatively, you can do:

`SELECT id FROM student_details WHERE student_emailid='$email'` and update that ID.

Finally, use POST and bind your params as others have suggested. (If you F5 the page, it'll update again if the action is GET. POST is marginally more difficult to tamper with, but should NOT be relied upon as a security measure in itself.)